# Error to fit generator object to model: No. of arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am creating a model for Image Captioning that uses CNN and LSTM. I am training the model by generating batches. But I am getting an error while executing "model.fit" that takes the generator object. If anyone could help?

Below is the code for the generator function and the model used. I don't how what is wrong here!

```
def data_generator(train_descriptions,encoding_train,word_to_idx,max_len,num_photos_per_batch):
  X1,X2,y = [],[],[]
  n = 0
  while True:
    for key, desc_list in train_descriptions.items():
      n+=1
      photo = encoding_train[key+".jpg"]
      for desc in desc_list:
        seq = [word_to_idx[word] for word in desc.split() if word in word_to_idx]
        for i in range(1,len(seq)):
          in_seq = seq[0:i]
          out_seq = seq[i]
          in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq],maxlen=max_len,value=0,padding='post')[0]
          out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq],num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
          X1.append(photo)
          X2.append(in_seq)
          y.append(out_seq)
      if n==num_photos_per_batch:
        yield [[np.array(X1),np.array(X2),np.array(y)]]
        X1,X2,y = [],[],[]
        n=0 
# image feature extractor model, inputs image feature vector

input_img_fea = Input(shape=(2048,))
inp_img1 = Dropout(0.3)(input_img_fea)
inp_img2 = Dense(256,activation='relu')(inp_img1)

#partial caption sequence model, inputs captions
input_cap = Input(shape=(max_len,))
inp_cap1 = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,output_dim=50,mask_zero=True)(input_cap)
inp_cap2 = Dropout(0.3)(inp_cap1)
inp_cap3 = LSTM(256)(inp_cap2)

decoder1 = add([inp_img2,inp_cap3])
decoder2 = Dense(256,activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(vocab_size,activation='softmax')(decoder2)

#Merge 2 networks
model = Model(inputs=[input_img_fea,input_cap],outputs=outputs)
model.summary()

model.layers[2].set_weights([embedding_output])
model.layers[2].trainable = False
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam")

epochs = 20
number_pics_per_bath = 3
steps = len(train_descriptions)//number_pics_per_bath

for i in range(epochs):
  generator = data_generator(train_descriptions,encoding_train,word_to_idx,max_len,number_pics_per_bath)
  model.fit(generator,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=steps)
  model.save('./model_'+str(i)+'.h5')
```

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 200, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Layer "{layer_name}" expects {len(input_spec)} input(s),'

ValueError: Layer "model_2" expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: You need to pass inputs with a single bracket, not double, I would just return a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Could you spot the line? Which input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shape in the yield is wrong, you need to provide 2 inputs not 3. Try this:

```
yield [[np.array(X1), np.array(X2)] , [np.array(y)]]
```